# Why is the div floating all the way to the right when it is float :left?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to get the div to align under the 'featured' section on this page: http://paulsavagejr.com/home.html. Instead, the div is aligning with the right side of the screen even though it has `float:left` included in its code.

I thought maybe if I defined height on a previous div it would force it down to the right position but that did not work. I also tried `display:inline-block` as an alternative to see if that helped but only made the divs even more out of place.

The code for the div is:

```
#clients {
float: left;
background-color: #E2E3E5;
color: #1A1B1D;
width: 19%;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

The full style sheet is found here: http://www.paulsavagejr.com/assets/css/style-desktop.css

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Particularly, what may be affecting the appearance of the divs using `display:inline-block` as I know that is more suited for layouts. I've just not been able to get the hang of it for some reason.

Comment: Would you be so kind to give us a fiddle example ?

Comment: What is the page suppose to look like? Your layout is sensitive/responsive to the with of the page, and in some cases, it looks okay.  You may have some conceptual issues related to clearing floats and so on.  What is your level of expertise with CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 123 on your stylesheet, remove `float: left;`, in summary you should only have this now:

**CSS:**

```
#clients {
    background-color: #E2E3E5;
    color: #1A1B1D;
    width: 19%;
    padding-left: 3%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :-) Tbh I'm not quite sure. Here is a mockup of a layout based off yours -  **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wz357qLe/)**. Because box2 has a larger height it forces the last div to float right on the page. I've never came across this problem because I normally make responsive fluid grid layouts, so it's a new one for me.

Comment: If you change box2's height back to 150px or just delete lines 7-10 in the css you will see it will `float:left` as should.